# ambiguous overloaded call to 'sign' Delphi

Tags: delphi, compiler-errors, sign

I am trying to use the function Sign() with a DOUBLE variable, but it keeps
giving me the erro message "ambiguous overloaded call to 'sign'".

This also happens when trying to use an INTEGER variable, or any variable for that matter.

Why is this happening, and how can this be fixed?

The code I am using is the following:

```
var
  CB : double;
  SignCB : TValueSign;
begin
  CB := Random(1000)-500;
  SignCB := Sign(CB);  
end;
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include your code (with the relevant variable declarations). It's hard to answer questions about code that won't compile if you *don't include the code*. (The problem is because the compiler can't tell which version of `Sign` it should use, but it's difficult to tell you how to fix it without seeing your code.)

Comment: @KenWhite Alright. Code included!

Comment: In this case the `uses` might have been more useful (or not). Some unit contains `sign` but not your meant `math.Sign`, just use the namespace like `math.Sign(xy)`

Comment: This code compiles fine in Delphi 2007 (what I happen to have open right now). I think @bummi has it right.

Comment: You are right. I changed it to Math.Sign and now it seems to work. thanks!

Comment: @AidVllasaliu, it appears what you have conflicting `Sign` overload elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Sign` function that you are trying to call is [`Math.Sign`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.Sign). There are in fact multiple overloaded versions of that function, for the commonly used numeric types.

If the only `Sign` that is visible to your code are the overloads in the `Math` unit then you will not encounter that error. The only plausible conclusion is that you have defined another function named `Sign` that clashes.

One solution is to fully qualify the function call. Call `Math.Sign()` instead of `Sign()`.

Perhaps a better solution would be to change the name of your `Sign` function. By using the same name as a primitive RTL function you are asking for future confusion. I would suggest that you take this latter course of action.